# Resize an Image Inside a UIImage before saving in directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have this code which gets the image inside my `UIImage` (connected with IB called 'c1_1') and should save in my directory folder:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *c1_1;

if (c1_1.image != nil)
        {
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                 NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/ImagensApp/ImagensClientes/%@_%@_Cliente.jpg",list[0],abc]];
            NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(c1_1.image, 70);
            [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        }
```

This code works, but I want to resize the image to scale 200x200, how I can do this before saving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling an image is just a few lines of code that

- creates a memory bitmap
- draws the image into that bitmap
- and then gets the new image from the bitmap

like this

```
- (UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height )];
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return( result );
}
```

Comment: Works! and to call I want to put this inside my code  NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([self scaleImage:c1_1.image toSize:CGSizeMake(150, 150)], 70);